# If statement checking array value not getting expected results PHP

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

***EDIT
I figured it out after looking at the source the Home being echoed by print_r actually was a link and had an  tag among other elements that is why my comparison did not match. 
****END EDIT

Not sure why I am still seeing the output since my if statement should not send it to the screen based on the results of the data echoed to the screen:

```
  echo count($breadcrumb);
  print_r($breadcrumb);
 if(count($breadcrumb) === 1 && $breadcrumb[0] === 'Home'){
     echo "Is not showing";
  }else{

  return $output;

  }
```

What I see on the page for my echos is:

```
1Array ( [0] => Home )
```

I feel like both of the criteria of the if statement were met so why is output still getting to the screen?

Comment: have you checked if the data types match? try `var_dump` . `===` operator also matches the data types.

Comment: I figured it out after looking at the source the Home being echoed by print_r actually was a link and had an <a> tag among other elements that is why my comparison did not match.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the below code is "Is not showin", since condition is satisfied.

```
if(count($breadcrumb) === 1 && $breadcrumb[0] === 'Home'){
   echo "Is not showing";
 }else{

  return $output; 
}
```